# Intercept kafka poll request with SpringAOP

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-aop

I would like to intercept the kafka poll request in order to log some informations like response time, available message number. I used springAOP without any success. I'm already using @KafkaListener to consume message one by one but i would like to track also the poll request. Has anyone done something like that before?

Comment: Sharing the code that you have already tried would give you specific answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can do that implementing (via extension) a `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory`. In the overridden `createConsumer()` method you wrap the `super` result into the mentioned AOP proxy and intercept via your `MethodInterceptor` the `poll(Duration)` call.